# Stored procedure - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ''

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am new to stored procedures and I want to get the id of some row by using that row column 'name'. Following is the stored procedure that I used.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_SHGO_ID] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @TableName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@SHGO_Name VARCHAR(100)
    ,@Ret int OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SHGO_ID AS INT

    SET @Query = N'SELECT @x=ID FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE SHGO_Name=' +@SHGO_Name
    EXECUTE  sp_executesql  @Query,N'@x int out', @SHGO_ID out

    SET @Ret = @SHGO_ID
END
```

Below is how I try to execute it.

```
USE [UL_SLHEV]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @Ret int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_Get_SHGO_ID]
        @TableName = N'dbo.SHGO',
        @SHGO_Name = N'AITKEN SPENCE',
        @Ret = @Ret OUTPUT

SELECT  @Ret as N'@Ret'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

But I am getting the following error. Can anyone help me with this?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SPENCE'.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Welcome to world of concatenated SQL string. Your query is: `SELECT @x=ID FROM dbo.SGHO WHERE SHGO_Name=AITKEN SPENCE`

Comment: You need to quote strings - your query is ending up as `SELECT @x=ID FROM dbo.SHGO WHERE SHGO_Name=AITKEN SPENCE`.  Or better yet, use the parameters instead, rather than concatenating SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add escaped single quotes so that your dynamic SQL string is valid:

```
SET @Query = N'SELECT @x=ID FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE SHGO_Name=''' +@SHGO_Name + ''''
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Can  you please explain what I am doing wrong there? Why I need to add escaped single quotes only for @SHGO_Name?

Comment: The comments to your question already pointed out why.  `WHERE SHGO_Name=AITKEN SPENCE` isn't valid SQL, because AITKEN SPENCE is a string value, and in SQL, string values have to be delimited with single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

First of all please use parameter binding:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_SHGO_ID] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @TableName VARCHAR(50)  -- should be SYSNAME
    --,@schemaName SYSNAME    -- schema and table should be separated
    ,@SHGO_Name VARCHAR(100)
    ,@Ret int OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SHGO_ID AS INT

    SET @Query = N'SELECT @x=ID FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE SHGO_Name=@SHGO_Name'
    EXECUTE  sp_executesql  
        @Query
       ,N'@x int out, @SHGO_Name VARCHAR(100)'
       ,@SHGO_ID out
       ,@SHGO_Name;

    SET @Ret = @SHGO_ID
END
```

Second you should use [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to secure table name, third indetifiers are type of `SYSNAME`.

Before you move on, please read **[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)**